# Use a Spring Boot @Value where a constant is required

Tags: spring-boot

When using Spring Boot, in a Java class marked `@Service`, I can pull in a configured value from an `application.yml` file ...

```
foo:
  bar:
    baz: value
```

... using `@Value` ...

```
@Value("${foo.bar.baz}")
private String fooBarBaz;
```

Is there a way to use a configured value where a constant is required?

```
@KafkaListener(topics = HERE)
public void listen(String message) {
```

If I substitute `"${foo.bar.baz}"` for `HERE`, that just puts the constant literal string there instead of reading from my `application.yml` file, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a SpEL expression such as:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{${foo.bar.baz}}")
public void listen(String message) {
```

Cf: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/361#issuecomment-313200577